# Различие массива и строки в си

Tags: c

Я начинающий, не ругайтесь сильно :)
Я не понимаю причину, по которой вывод массива типа char с помощью %s не равен выводу по элементу.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    char a = '1';
    char b = '2';
    char c[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        if (i == 0)
            c[i] = a;
        else 
            c[i] = b;
    }
    printf("%s\n",c);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("%c", c[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

все очень просто. Достаточно спросить себя, "как printf узнает длину строки?" а делает это очень просто - по нулевому символу в конце строки. У Вас же такого нет и printf выводит до тех пор, пока такой не найдет. Вам повезло, он нашелся быстро. А могло и не повезти.

Я вот так поменяю программу и все будет работать

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    char a = '1';
    char b = '2';
    char c[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        if (i == 0)
            c[i] = a;
        else 
            c[i] = b;
    }
    c[2] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n",c);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("%c", c[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Можно исправить и меньшей кровью. Просто уточнить для printf кол-во символов

```
printf("%.2s\n",c);
```

ну или если не хочется хардкодить, можно даже так

```
printf("%.*s\n",2,c); // двойку можно вынести теперь
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!